# How do I set a Three.js Plane rotation with an Object3D's local rotation?

Tags: three.js, 3d, vector-graphics

I have a [Plane](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Plane), and a [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group) of objects, which has a rotation. I need to set the plane's surface normal to always be rotated in accordance with the Group's rotation (this rotation changes based on user input).

I've tried things like this, which sort of work:

```
onGroupRotation() {
    const vec = orbitGroup.rotation.toVector3();
    orbitPlane.set(vec, 0);
}
```

The problem is that the rotation's magnitude seems too small: the plane's rotation doesn't quite match that of the `orbitGroup`.

I don't really know linear algebra and I'm still learning about things like vector dot and cross products. I'm sure there's a simple solution someone more knowledgeable can help me fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default forward vector for 3D objects like groups or meshes is `(0, 0, 1)`. If you set the surface normal to this value and apply the quaternion of the group, you should get the desired result.

```
plane.normal.set( 0, 0, 1 ).applyQuaternion( group.quaternion );
```

Comment: Thank you. Now how do I rotate this plane 90 degrees along its X axis? Looking at the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Plane)... I just can't figure this out.

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/187506/add-90-degrees-to-transformrotation.html  Something like this works: https://gist.github.com/nikolas/5cb72bc5f5bc64567e66a3f17b4b834a